# Print in multiple HTML files

Tags: perl, html-parsing, lwp

I'm relatively new to Perl. I have a list of URLs from which I want to extract only the text and print it in different files. Here is a sample of my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use locale;
use warnings;
#use diagnostics;
use utf8;

binmode(STDIN, "encoding(utf8)");
binmode(STDOUT, "encoding(utf8)");
binmode(STDERR, "encoding(utf8)");

use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::Parse;

open (CLEANURL, '<:utf8', "clean_keyword_url_5.3.txt")  || die ("Cannot open File\n");
open(STORECODE, '>:utf8', "Bstored_keyword_url_5.3.txt")  || die ("Cannot open File\n");

my $url2parse;
my @arg = <CLEANURL>;
close (CLEANURL);

foreach my $arg(@arg) {
    $url2parse = parse_html(get($arg))->format;
    print STORECODE $url2parse;
}

close (STORECODE);
```

in the `clean_keyword_url_5.3.txt` I have links like :

http://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2013/01/31/1548850-aulon-l-activite-est-paralysee.html#xtor=RSS-6

http://tdg.ch/monde/faits-divers/Deux-alpinistes-meurent-dans-une-avalanche-en-Isere/story/10446351

so mainly French or Swiss local newspaper. I'd like to print each link in a separate folder and I tried to do this with an array of file handles and using the "getstore" method of `LWP::Simple`, however I'm unable to make the loop on all the links. It creates all the files but with only print the content of one URL in each of them. I can't find any information on running `LWP::Simple` on an array, it seems that everybody uses this module with only one or two URLs.

I also had an idea with a hash which looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use locale;
use warnings;
#use diagnostics;
use utf8;

binmode(STDIN, "encoding(utf8)");
binmode(STDOUT, "encoding(utf8)");
binmode(STDERR, "encoding(utf8)");

use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::Parse;

open (CLEANURL, '<:utf8', "clean_keyword_url_5.3.txt") || die ("Cannot open File\n");
#open(STORECODE, '>:utf8', "Bstored_keyword_url_5.3.html")  || die ("Cannot open File\n");

my $url2parse;
my @arg = <CLEANURL>;
close (CLEANURL);

my @filehandles;
my $i;

for ($i = 0; $i<@arg; $i++){
    local *FILE;
    open (FILE, '>:utf8', "Bstored_keyword_url_5.3.$i.html")|| die;
    push (@filehandles, *FILE);
}

foreach my $arg(@arg) {
    $url2parse = parse_html(get($arg))->format;
    foreach my $file(@filehandles){
       my %hash = {key => $file};
       $hash{key} .= $val;
       print $file "$hash{key}";    
    }
}

#close (STORECODE);
```

You may noticed that this code doesn't work. The problem is that I can't wrap my mind around it.

So if you have any idea, it would be very helpful.
Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

(see update 1 at the end)

#### General comments:

It is very nice to see that you are trying to use Best Practices when writing Perl (strict, warnings, and explicit encodings). If using `locale` is good could be debated…. There are three things that you can do better:

1. Declare variables in their innermost possible scope.
2. Use lexical filehandles
3. Check for errors

#### Your first script

- It is considered a best practice to open filehandles into lexical variables: `open my $fh, "<", $filename or die $!` or something. The `$!` contains the reason for the failure. Include it in your output, as it includes invaluable hints for the *actual* reson that your open failed (missing rights, no such path, etc).
- When read from your files, the urls still have a trailing newline. Do `chomp @arg` to remove them, or `s/\s+$// for @arg;` to remove any trailing space characters.
- `LWP::Simple` can fail. You should check if you actually got a response:

  ```
  my $content = get $url;
  die "Didn't receive anything from $url" unless defined $content;
  ```

  I would prefer to use `LWP::UserAgent`, as this allows for more error checking:

  ```
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  ...;
  my $response = $ua->get($url);

  die "Request for $url failed: " . $response->status_line unless $response->is_sucess

  my $content = $response->decoded_content;
  ```
- The same goes for parsing HTML. Look up your modules documentation, and check for errors.

#### Second script

The same points all go for this second script. In addition:

- In your C-style for-loop, you iterate over the range from o to the max index of `@arg`. Also, the variable `$i` is only used inside the loop, so we declare it here:

  ```
  for my $i (0 .. $#arg) { ... }
  ```

  The `$#` sigil gives the highest index of an array. `..` is the range operator in list context. Even if you wouldn't want to use ranges, you could have declared your var like `for(my $i = 0; $i < @arg; $i++) { ... }`.
- The `local` function takes the name of a global variable, backs it up on a special stack, and allows you to temporarily assign a new value to that name. The old variable is restored once the current scope is left (scope is roughly delimited by curly braces). Don't use it, unless you are really forced (read “Coping with Scoping”). Please be aware, that barewords, typeglobs, references to typeglobs, and filehandles are not the same thing. Just open your filehandles into lexical variables, and don't dabble with typeglobs, and some bugs may dissolve.

  ```
  my @filehandles;
  for my $i (0 .. $#arg) {
    my $filename = "Bstored_keyword_url_5.3.$i.html";
    open my $fh, "<:utf8", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
    push @filehandles, $fh;
    # lexical filehandles are automatically closed once their reference count hits zero.
  }
  ```

  Or, a bit advanced, we can see that there is a direct mapping between integers and filehandles, and express the array as this mapping. Totally equivalent to the above:

  ```
  # how map works: OUTPUT = map { BLOCK } INPUT-LIST
  my @filehandles = map {
    # current value is in $_
    my $filename = "Bstored_keyword_url_5.3.$_.html";
    open my $fh, "<:utf8", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
    $fh; # last statement determines what is put into the array.
  } 0 .. $#arg;
  ```
- Hashes are nice. Do be aware that hashes are constructed as an even-valued list. The `{}` constructs an *anonymous hash reference*, just like the `[]` doesn't construct an array, but an *anonymous array reference*. References are always kept in scalars:

  ```
  my $hashref = { foo => 1, bar => 3 };
  say $hashref->{foo}; # dereference arrow needed
  ```

  or

  ```
  my %hash = ( foo => 1, bar => 3 );
  say $hash{foo};
  ```

  The parens are only there to sort out precedence, they dont "create" a list or an array.
- As I just used it: The `say` function is available in perl 5.10 or better. You can activate it with `use feature 'say'` or `use 5.010` (or any higher version number). It works exactly like `print`, but appends the output seperator `$\` (usually a newline) to the output.
- In the final loop, you use the variable `$val`. Where did that get from? Also, don't append a string to a filehandle. This stringifies the filehandle, which (a) renders it unusable, and (b) provides a fairly useless string (maybe `IO::File=GLOB(0xdeadbeef)`). Also, don't use a hash if you only use it for one (!) key.

#### Links

1. [LWP::Simple documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aSimple)
2. [LWP::UserAgent documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent)
3. [HTML::Parse](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aParse) says it's deprecated. See [HTML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aParser) or [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder).
4. [Coping with Scoping](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html): Why you should never use global, or "local" variables.

### Update 1

Yourr new code is fairly nice as well (I'd *love* to see more people using `strict` from the start…). Except that you forget to put anything into `$url2parse`, and that you find some creative uses for looping ;-)

Using `getstore` or `mirror` or what it is called these days is a good idea. This means we don't have to open a file handle manually.

This it could be coded:

```
...;
# ↓ lexical filehandles 'n stuff
open my $CLEANURL, "<:utf8", ... or die ...;
my $counter = 0;
while(my $link = <$CLEANURL>) {
  chomp $link; # remove evil newlines
  my $status = mirror($link => "Cstored_keyword_url_5.3.$counter.txt");
  200 == $status or warn "WARNING: fetching $link failed with status $status";
  $counter++;
}
```

That's only one loop instead of three. As I use the `mirror` function from `LWP::Simple` (`getstore` would work as well), I just have to pass a filename, and don't care for filehandles.

The `while (my $line = <$filehandle>) { ... }` is commonly used in Perl to read a file line-by-line. On small programs like this, that is irrelevant, but its a good habit when your data scales…

In manual code, the above might look like:

```
...;
my $counter = 0;
while (my $link = <$CLEANURL>) {
  chomp $link;
  my $filename = "Cstored_keyword_url_5.3.$counter.txt";
  open my $fh, ">:utf8", $filename or die "Couldn't open $filename: $!";
  my $content = get $link;
  if (defined $content) { print $fh $content }
  else                  { warn "WARNING: failed to fetch $link" }
  # $fh autocloses here
  $counter++;
}
```

I am still in favour of using `LWP::UserAgent`, as that lends more insight to failures.

Once you can fetch & process your URLs correctly, parallelism might be a next step to speed things up.

Comment: Thank you, I actually posted my reply in another answer... it seems that I'm not that good at using the stackoverflow interface. However, if you want to check my answer/question it would be very helpful... Thanks again !!!

Comment: @user2007958 I did a small update. Not quite tested, but it might steer you into a more correct direction.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll to test your code as soon as tomorow... at first glance it seems to be the answer to all my problems... I'll keep you updated on my progress... and yes, you are right on LWP::UserAgent

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to amon this is the the updated code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use locale;
use warnings;
#use diagnostics;
use utf8;

binmode(STDIN, "encoding(utf8)");
binmode(STDOUT, "encoding(utf8)");
binmode(STDERR, "encoding(utf8)");

use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::Parse;

open (CLEANURL, '<:utf8', "clean_keyword_url_5.3.txt")  || die ("Cannot open File\n");
open (STORECODE, '>:utf8', "all_articles.txt")  || die ("Cannot open File\n");

my $counter = 0;

while(my $link = <CLEANURL>){
    chomp ($link);
    my $filename = "cstored_keyword_url_5.3.$counter.txt";
    open (my $fh, ">:utf8", $filename) || die "Couldn't open $filename: $!";
    my $content = get($link);
    unless (defined $link){
        warn "WARNING: Failed to fetch $link";
    }
    $content = parse_html($content) || die "Couldn't parse $content";
    my $text = $content->format;
    if (defined $text){
       print $fh $text;
       print STORECODE $text;
    }else{
       warn "WARNING: Failed to fetch $link";
    }
    $counter++; 
}

close (CLEANURL);
close (STORECODE);
```

As I already said in my orginal post the "clean_keyword_url_5.3.txt" contains URLs to news articles. It has to be one URL by line in order to use get method from the LWP::Simple.
Thanks again !!!

Comment: There is one issue with your code: If the `get` fails, the `parse_html` function will likely throw an error. You should really check if the return value of `get` is defined, not if the return value of `format` (which is unlikey to fail) is ok. → `my $html = get($link); unless(defined $link){warn ...; next;} my $tree = parse_html($html) or die "Couldn't parse ..."; my $content = $tree->format; print $fh $content; print STORECODE $content;`

Comment: You are right, I updated the code. I'll keep in mind to always check if the output of any method of a module is actually working.

Comment: ah, you accidentally introduced a new bug: `open my $fh, ">:utf8", $filename || die` parses as `open my $fh, ">:utf8", ($filename || die)`. Either use parens around the args for `open`, or use the `or` operator, which has far lower precedence.

Comment: Yep, I've updated the code again. It seems to run flawlessly for me now.